# How to get max value of column type integer stored as type text in sqlite table

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to get MAX value of one column in sqlite table.
The problem is the type of data is long in fact but stored as text in the table.How can I do with this strange situation.
I've tried of this below but it's not correct

```
SELECT MAX(ColumnName) FROM TABLE;
```

But it returned value but not correct!Please someone can help me

Answer (score 1):

you could always cast the text to an int:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(ColunmName) as int) from TABLE
```

Comment: it works like a charm! You are life saver!thanks you @SaggingRufus

Comment: No Problem! Glad I could answer your question.