# Integer stored as String returning wrong MAX value Sqlite Android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I've stored an Integer as a string in my Sqlite Database on Android but now I need to find the max value of the data. I have the following code:

```
    public String getMaxPageFromMainDB(){
    String maxNoStr =null;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(donebottombar) FROM customers",null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        maxNoStr = cursor.getString(0);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return maxNoStr;
}
```

When it comes to sorting the max value of numbers stored, 9 is coming before 11.

Is there anything wrong with my code or a way to better sort this without changing the database schema?

As answered below with a little change in code:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(CAST(donebottombar AS INTEGER)) FROM customers",null);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the stored data type is different from how you want to compare the values, you have to [convert](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr) them:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(donebottombar AS INT )) FROM customers;
SELECT MAX(CAST(donebottombar AS TEXT)) FROM customers;
```

Comment: Thanks, you put me on the right track. Syntax was the key. The following code worked for me: Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(CAST(donebottombar AS INTEGER)) FROM customers",null);

Comment: @NoChance See the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype).

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do integer calculations on a string.

When using MAX with strings, the "MAX" string is the one at the top of the table.

Quote from "http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0240__Aggregate-Functions/UseMAXwithstrings.htm":
When you use MAX() with strings, the strings are ordered alphabetically with the "maximum" string being at the bottom of a list and the "minimum" string being at the top of the list.

You need to save that value as an integer in your database and not as a string.

Comment: I guessed that but I'm hoping for a fix rather than an overhaul of my code. I notice there is a CAST as INT in Sqlite but is there an equivalent for Android Sqlite?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41634060/how-to-get-max-value-of-column-type-integer-stored-as-type-text-in-sqlite-table